# docker services error with iptables after hard reboot

Tags: docker, iptables

after hard reboot some of my mailcow service can't up
and I see very strange error:

_ # docker-compose up mysql-mailcow
mailcowdockerized_unbound-mailcow_1 is up-to-date
Starting mailcowdockerized_mysql-mailcow_1 ...
Starting mailcowdockerized_mysql-mailcow_1 ... error

ERROR: for mailcowdockerized_mysql-mailcow_1  Cannot start service mysql-mailcow: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mailcowdockerized_mysql-mailcow_1 (51ef83fe79434e8d985b4f451631001a97f9912be630509abcbed92065f5da1e):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 13306 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.22.1.6:3306 ! -i br-mailcow: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--dport"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information. (exit status 2)) ERROR: for mysql-mailcow  Cannot start service mysql-mailcow: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mailcowdockerized_mysql-mailcow_1 (51ef83fe79434e8d985b4f451631001a97f9912be630509abcbed92065f5da1e):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 13306 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.22.1.6:3306 ! -i br-mailcow: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--dport" Try` iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
(exit status 2))
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project. `

Comment: Dunno if this thread might help you in any way https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38759

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with `xt_tcpudp` modules on ubuntu in `linux-image-5.4.0-84-generic`

I changed to `linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic` and everything start works!